# How to activate Baseline Profiles - Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, benchmarking, android-jetpack, baseline-profile

I generated Baseline Profiles and saw promising results in my Macrobenchmark test:
[image]

I put the baseline-prof.txt file in the main folder next to the Manifest.xml.
When I run the app in release mode I cannot see a visible difference when performing the action I generated the baseline profile for.

Can I only see the benefit of baseline profiles when installing the app via Google Play store? Am I missing something?

Also what do those P50, P90, P95 mean?
The docs say:
“These measurements are collected in distribution: 50th, 90th, 95th, and 99th percentile.”

Not sure what that means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, baseline profiles are not used when running locally. It is possible to [manually side load](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles#measuring-baseline) one but using Macrobenchmark like you are doing is much easier.

P50 etc is a statistical distribution of your measured results. You can read it like

P90 means 90% of cases were measured to be better than this. Or inversely 10% of cases were worse.

Comment: Do I have to do anything else than putting the baseline-prof.txt file in the main folder next to the Manifest.xml? Or can I just simply generate my signed release bundle and upload to google play?
And whats the difference here besides running it locally and uploading it to GP?
Why are the Baseline Profiles working when downloading from Google Play but not when I run the APK locally?